# Surface Headphones on Windows 11

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-11

I have the Surface Headphones (the first version, not the 2), and I've been using them on Windows 10 without any problems. Whenever I switch them on, they show as two separate audio devices, "Headphones" for output stereo sound (such as listening to music) plus "Headset" for input/output mono sound (such as videoconferencing).

A few days ago I upgraded my computer to Windows 11. Since then, my Surface Headphones show as just one device, "Headphones", rather than two. I can videoconference successfully, but there is no apparent way to switch to the output-only stereo mode for music listening, as before the Windows 11 upgrade.

If I look in the system settings screen, there is a "Headphones" output device as well as a "Headset" input device. I guess both together make up the "Heaphones" device I can use for videoconferencing. But there is no way to switch to stereo mode.

Why is this so and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You might need to look for updated bluetooth drivers for whatever adapter you have. The windows built in drivers might not support A2DP which would be the stereo headphones.

Comment: Thanks, @Mokubai, but neither Windows Update nor the computer manufacturer seem to be offering an updated driver.

Comment: Check the property's for the device, there may be a setting to split them up. Also, in sound manager, you can edit the individual settings, perhaps pinning that screen to your taskbar will allow you easy access.

Comment: @Greenreader9 Thanks, but I can't see any setting like that.